# Dateformat in android

Tags: java, android, date

I want to get the date format like this feb 17,2011 18:13 in android...

Thanks.

Comment: Good that `SimpleDateFormat` supports future dates then :)

Comment: @Bozho, great, hope ain't too expensive. I'll definitely take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd','yyyy HH:mm");
    Date someDate = new Date();
    String date = sf.format(someDate);
```

Comment: look at the documentation. There is an `a` switch that adds am/pm, and lower-case `hh` for 12-hour format

Answer (score 4):

The class `SimpleDateFormat` provides the necessary tools to do this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDateTimeInstance` method of `DateFormat` class

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28%29)